# GPO Registry and Startup Scripts failing to apply

Tags: windows, group-policy

I've been working on a relatively simple GPO to lock down some machines that will act as "kiosks". All the policies/preferences etc that I've set have worked fine except for registry changes (using Computer Config > Preferences > Windows Settings > Registry) and startup scripts in an attempt to have the registry changes occur via a batch/PS script (Computer Config > Policies > Windows Settings > Scripts).
In both cases, gpresult doesn't show these changes attempting to be made at all. They don't show up in my results.html anywhere whatsoever.

The OU that my GPO is applying to is blocking inheritance and there are no "enforced" GPOs above mine.

Anyone have any experience with this? Again, every single other change I've made in the GPO has worked (or at least I can see them in gpresult to see if/why they're failing to apply).

Comment: do you have computer where you want to apply this gpo in the security filtering or only Authenticated users? Best regards,

Comment: Create a new GPO, do not modify anything else. Put in a dummy script that does not change anything important on the target machine and see if that script is now getting applied.